# Can't iterate through tensorflow Dataset created from LibSVM generator. NoneType does not support item assignment

Tags: python, tensorflow, ranking, tensorflow-datasets

I try to run the [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/examples/tf_ranking_libsvm.ipynb) of tensorflow ranking with some custom data. The example works with their data.

Basically I want to create a tensorflow Dataset with the function `tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_generator()` to get the dataset for tf ranking.

I've created the dataset with

```py
from sklearn.datasets import dump_svmlight_file
dump_svmlight_file(X=X, y=y, f=f, query_id=query_id)
```

And it looks like this:

```
0 qid:10 0:53156 1:6456 2:700
1 qid:10 0:48112 1:3535 2:700
2 qid:10 0:48112 1:3655 2:16500
3 qid:10 0:51641 1:8871 2:1200
4 qid:10 0:13207 1:2790 2:400
5 qid:10 0:8175  1:1656 2:700
6 qid:21 0:8175  1:1776 2:2700
7 qid:21 0:9620  1:2424 2:1600
8 qid:21 0:8079  1:2443 2:700
9 qid:25 0:13428 1:3777 2:800
```

I then create the dataset with the following code:

```py
_NUM_FEATURES_OWN=3
_LIST_SIZE_OWN=10

train_dataset_OWN = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
      tfr.data.libsvm_generator(_TRAIN_DATA_PATH_OWN, _NUM_FEATURES_OWN, _LIST_SIZE_OWN),
      output_types=(
          {str(k): tf.float32 for k in range(1,_NUM_FEATURES_OWN+1)},
          tf.float32
      ),
      output_shapes=(
          {str(k): tf.TensorShape([_LIST_SIZE_OWN, 1])
            for k in range(1,_NUM_FEATURES_OWN+1)},
          tf.TensorShape([_LIST_SIZE_OWN])
      )
    )
```

And get the dataset. But when I try to iterate through it I'll get the error message:

```py
train_dataset_OWN.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

```
InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 207, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 449, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_ranking/python/data.py", line 477, in inner_generator
    num_features, list_size, doc_list)

  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_ranking/python/data.py", line 424, in _libsvm_generate
    features.get(feature_id)[idx, 0] = value

TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]
```

I've created an example notebook here: 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hAVJrQmbXD5h1pZfCKpkvSJib4_OaL1J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been wrestling with the same problem.

What worked for me was indexing the features from 1 instead of from 0, for example:

```
0 qid:10 1:53156 2:6456 3:700
1 qid:10 1:48112 2:3535 3:700
2 qid:10 1:48112 2:3655 3:16500
3 qid:10 1:51641 2:8871 3:1200
4 qid:10 1:13207 2:2790 3:400
5 qid:10 1:8175  2:1656 3:700
6 qid:21 1:8175  2:1776 3:2700
7 qid:21 1:9620  2:2424 3:1600
8 qid:21 1:8079  2:2443 3:700
9 qid:25 1:13428 2:3777 3:800
```

Comment: Did you mean to change the indexes (first column)? They look the same to me.

Comment: I mean adding one to each of the features (left of the colon)

Comment: That worked for me as well, thanks! I just created the dataset with 
`dump_svmlight_file(X=X, y=y, f=f, query_id=query_id, zero_based=False)`